# Node.js 344 error Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js

Trying to wrap my head around this error I get, I don't understand why. I seen a couple of posts with it, but they are all different cases and none kinda match mine. So appreciate help.
what i want to upload multiple files upload.
but I do file upload It's work just one.
but when i try to upload multiple files, it's not working
can you give me a answer?

```js
router.post('/contents/insert/upload', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
 
 var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
 
 form.parse(req);
// form.on("fileBegin", function (name, file){
//  console.log('upload come on3');
//  
//    });
    form.on("file", function (name, file){
        fs.readFile(file.path, function(error, data){
         var filePath = __dirname + '/../public/uploads/' + file.name;
         
         fs.writeFile(filePath, data, function(error){
          if(error){
           throw err;
           //res.redirect('back');
          }else {
           res.redirect('back');
          }
         });
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<form action="/adm/contents/insert/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
       <!-- <input type="file" name="file" />
       <input type="submit" /> -->
    <div class="file-field input-field">
        <div class="btn">
      <span>input images</span>
         <input type="file" name="file" multiple>
        </div>
          <div class="file-path-wrapper">
            <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
          </div>
       </div>
       <input type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" value="upload" />
   </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file` event will be triggered for every file in the upload, so eventually your code will issue `res.redirect()` for each uploaded file. This will cause the error (you can only issue a redirect, or send back a response, just once in the lifetime of a request).

Instead, you want to listen for the `end` event, and issue the redirect there:

```
form.on("file", function (name, file) {
  ...handle the file copy here, but don't call `res.redirect()` anywhere...
});

form.on("end", function() {
  res.redirect('back');
});
```

FWIW, it seems to me that you want to set the `uploadDir` option of Formidable, or use [`fs.rename()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback), instead of reading the file after upload and writing it to a new location (which isn't very efficient).

Comment: I add the code}else {
           form.on("end", function() {
              res.redirect('back');
            });
          }what you write. It's working many thanks. but i don't know why browser is keep loading...even it inserted

Comment: You shouldn't add the `end` handler _inside_ the `file` handler, but on the same level. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It's working clarify!! chose your answer